I want to change icons(Play and Pause) while textToSpeech speaking and stop in RecyclerView Android
I want to make ChatScreen like ChatGPT . In ChatScreen i want to change play - pause icons while TextToSpeech speaking or stop in RecyclerView. I'm Working in this since three or four days.
I Tried This but i can't get Perfect solution.

Here is my Adapter
class ChatAdapter(
var context: Context,
private var chatList: ArrayList<ChoicesItem>,
private var textToSpeech: TextToSpeech,
private var copyClick: (Int) -> Unit,
private var forwardClick: (Int) -> Unit,
private var speechClick: (Int, ViewHolder) -> Unit,
private var pauseClick: (ViewHolder) -> Unit

) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
   class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var message: AppCompatTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage)
    var forward = view.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.ivForward)
    var ivPlay = view.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.ivPlay)
    var ivPause = view.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.ivPause)
    var copy = view.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.ivCopy)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return if (chatList[viewType].isSend!!) {
        ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_chat_send_message, parent, false)
        )
    } else {
        ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_chat_receive_message, parent, false)
        )
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return chatList.size
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (chatList[position].isSend!!) {
        holder.message.text = chatList[position].text
    } else {
        holder.message.text = chatList[position].text?.trim()
        holder.copy.setOnClickListener {
            copyClick.invoke(position)
        }
        holder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener {
            speechClick.invoke(position, holder)
        }
        holder.ivPause.setOnClickListener {
            pauseClick.invoke(holder)
        }
        holder.forward.setOnClickListener {
            forwardClick.invoke(position)
        }
    }
}
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

}
This function set ChatAdapter
fun setData() {
    textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(activity) {}
    textToSpeech.language = Locale.US
    chatList = ArrayList()
    val model = (ChoicesItem(
        activity.getString(R.string.stop),
        0,
        activity.getString(com.hashmob.aichat.R.string.hi_there),
        false,
        null
    ))
    chatList.add(model)
    adapter = ChatAdapter(
        activity,
        chatList, textToSpeech,
        this::onCopyClick,
        this::onForwardClick,
        this::onSpeechClick,
        this::onPauseClick
    )
    binding.rcvChat.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    binding.rcvChat.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding.rcvChat.adapter = adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}


